# What test for repeated measurements with binary outcome?

Tags: repeated-measures, prediction, binary-data

Patients will be measured 1. during an operation and 2. after the operation.

Measurement 1: During the operation with machine1 to assess whether the transplanted tissue is at the right location (Outcome is binary (right location vs wrong location)).

Measurement 2:  Measurements will be performed 1 months after the operation with machine2 to assess whether the transplanted tissue is still at the right location and did not migrate (Outcome is binary, right/wrong location).

Research question: How well does a positive/negative result during measurement 1 predict the outcome of having the tissue at the right/wrong location at measurement2?

Which test is appropriate to answer the research question? I use SPSS.

Thank you for your time, I am looking forward to your replies. 
-Leif

Comment: do you have only two variables? measurement 1 and measurement 2?

Comment: @YuvalSp That is correct. But the measurements after the operation will be at multiple time points (1 week, 1 month, 3 months), however, if any of these show a change in location,the treatment will be considered 'failed', so the outcome is still binary:
During operation: 1 for good location, 0 for wrong location
After operation: At **all** time points good location: 1; at **any** time point wrong location: 0. 
I hope that makes it clear. 
(in regards to the edit: I wasn't aware that the return key will post the comment)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use McNemars test, which is a type of binary contingency test for paired data (like Chi Square taking into account within subject measurements). In SPSS go to:

Analyze $\rightarrow$ Nonparametric Tests $\rightarrow$  Legacy Dialogs $\rightarrow$ 2 Related Samples

[image]

If the test is significant ($p<0.05$ or whatever value you use) than the locations are not randomly distributed, meaning that the right/wrong location during surgery is likely influencing the location post-surgery.

Edit: If one of the cells in the 2x2 contingency table has 0 in it, but not due to any problem with the data itself - it is not a problem. This can be due to the fact that all of the patients who had the wrong location during operation have a wrong location post-operation (0 in the wrong-right cell). This will likely translate to a significant test.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! One follow-up question: Is it valid to use McNemars if one cell in the 2x2 table is empty (=0)?

Comment: see answer in edit above.

Comment: I ran the analysis and did not reach significane. However, I just want to be clear about the interpretation. The goal of the study is to test how well the pretest can predict the posttest result. So now that I did not reach significane, it means that my pretest _does_ predict the posttest, since people that stayed in location1 remain at location1 in the posttest. If I did reach significane it would mean that patients switched from one group to the other (e.g. from right location to wrong location). Is my interpretation correct?